# Solving a difference equation word problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I am having trouble with this extra credit problem.  Any hints would be appreciated!

> Suppose I give you money in the following way. Monday, I give you a dollar.  Tuesday, I give you half a dollar; Wednesday, I give you a third of Tuesday's amount, and so on.
>   (a) Find a difference equation for $y_n$, the amount of money I give you on the $n$th day. Then solve it.
>   (b) Assuming you are very patient, how much money will you collect from me?

Comment: I'm not sure what "and so on" means.  Are you supposing that the series is $1+\frac 12 + \frac 16 +\cdots +\frac 1{n!}+\cdots$? That makes sense, and sums to $e-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "difference equation", but I can answer part $b$.

As you should have figured out by now, on the $n$th day, you receive
$$\frac{1}{n!}$$
dollars. Thus the total amount of money is
$$\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...$$
Recall now that the MacLaurin series for $e^x$ is
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$$
Using this, you can say that the sum is
$$e-1\approx1.7$$
Which is the total amount of money you will receive.

Comment: The difference equation is $a_{n} = \frac {a_{n-1}}{n}$  Which could be seen a a preliminary step to what you show.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence is
$$y_1=1;\;y_{n+1}=\dfrac{y_{n}}{n+1}$$
The sequence is
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{120},\frac{1}{720},\frac{1}{5040},\ldots,\frac{1}{n!},\ldots\right\}$$
the $n-$th day the amount is $\dfrac{1}{n!}$

If there is enough time the sum of this daily money is close to $(e-1)$ dollars that is about $1.72$ dollars